# Is Ubuntu Core (20) on-topic on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, scope

**Is Ubuntu Core (20) on-topic on Ask Ubuntu?**

If so, does it have 10 years of support as advertised?

Comment: Canonical has advertised 10 years of *security updates* at https://ubuntu.com/core, which is one very important element of "support", but only one. Canonical did NOT promise 10 years of non-security bugfixes, 10 years of updated documentation, 10 years of answering questions, nor 10 years of help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, all versions of Ubuntu Core is on-topic.

Whether or not Canonical will keep their promise about 10 years of support - your crystal ball is as good as mine.

Comment: Some more depth on the subject, by yourself, here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1361838/57576

Comment: Yes, I would probably have referenced that at some point anyway - but thanks! 

Answer (score 3):

The [blog post](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-core-20-secures-linux-for-iot) announcing it says:

> Canonical secures business critical devices for 10 years.

So ask Canonical for your ten years of support.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. It is using Extended Security Maintenance. I think ESM is proof Canonical can do their part.

Comment: Good, so you should have no problem taking support requests to Canonical

Comment: Canonical, has sole ownership of Ubuntu Forums. You are right, they will help answer almost any Ubuntu question.

Comment: The blog post seems written to drive sales among IoT device producers --not us in the volunteer community-- so I wouldn't expect mention of the volunteer community. I don't see a snub of the volunteer community there. I DO see a lot of other blog posts encouraging volunteers to play with Ubuntu Core, provide feedback, and file bugs...just like the other releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 I didn't say it was a snub of anybody. I'm just saying the entity offering 10 years of support isn't the volunteer community, it's Canonical. So the one that should be asked for 10 years of support is Canonical, not some randos on the internet. None of us can make promises on their behalf.

Comment: @muru: But Canonical owns Ubuntu Forums and I think most of us that visit there consider ourselves part of the volunteer community. I have not seen Ubuntu Forums refuse to answer a question due to Ubuntu version.